# Where to buy fancy/cool looking toggle switches

Tags: switches, identification, components, toggle-switch, vintage

I wanted to know if anyone knows where to buy old, vintage style toggle switches like in the example photos. I have searched for toggle switches, and I have never found anything that looks remotely like the ones pictured. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Sony stereo receiver switches]

[image: IBM system 360 switches]

[image: inside of switch]

Comment: Poke around electronic surplus stores.  There are several online ones or there might be a few within driving distance of you.  You might have better luck searching for "leaf switches" instead of toggle switches.  Edit: also, you could try looking at thrift stores or the like and pulling switches out of old equipment.

Comment: You buy switches that come without a lever head cap and custom machine your own head cap.

Comment: Try peebay or shamazon.

Comment: Or try eBay or Amazon.  @Andyaka I would never shop at a store called Peebay or shamazon. They sound like they may be scams. Be careful when you type URLs into your browser.

Comment: As it happens I would never (AND I MEAN NEVER) shop at eBay or Amazon for electronic or electrical components. Shopping questions are off topic BTW.

Comment: please review images after you post them ... the last one is useless

Comment: @jsotola I know that that last image was bad, but it was the best I could find. Sorry.

Comment: ok, i see, it's off the web ... what does it actually show? ... looks like a relay

Comment: @jsotola The inside of the previous switch. That's why I included it. It didn't look like any other toggle switch that I had ever seen before. I was wondering if it was a different type of switch. I found the image from this video describing the inner workings of the panel the switch was from. https://youtu.be/WS-WtjwAAO0?t=337

Answer (score 2):

Toggle witches like those shown are not electric parts.  What you see are "knobs" and "button faces".  They attach to standard sliders, potentiometers and push buttons. They are custom made by injection molding, metal plating or other decoration techniques.  They attach to the shaft of the potentiometer, button or fader by small set screws or press on to the shaft with an "interference fit".

Google "knobs" or look at digikey.com for knobs.  Most are 1/4" diameter D shaft for older.  Newer are D-shaft 5mm with a set screw or or a knurled shaft with a press fit. Look up the shaft data before buying.  Stop by antique radio swap meets to buy old celluloid / Bakelite knobs or some funky chrome/satin metallized knobs as shown. Or, buy on old piece of equipment and simply remove them and recycle.